# List Custom Setting with getInstance() inconsistent based on API Version

Tags: customsetting

I've been looking at some older code and trying to figure out why it works.

They have something like this:

```
List_Custom_Setting__c settings = List_Custom_Setting__c.getInstance();
```

The [API doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm#apex_System_ListCustomSetting_instance_methods) does not mention a List custom setting `getinstance()` method without parameters, so it's curious.

`settings` above is filled with the the "first" value in the custom setting.  As far as I can tell, which row it returns is undefined, but there is only ever one record in this List custom setting, so there's no issue.  (Although, one could argue that perhaps a Hierarchy custom setting should have been used in this case.)

So I attempted to replicate this above statement in the Developer Console:

```
System.debug('1: '+List_Custom_Setting__c.getInstance());
```

and I received

```
1: List_Custom_Setting__c:{SetupOwnerId=005XXX}
```

whereas the code receives

```
1: List_Custom_Setting__c:{Id=a0mXXX,
IsDeleted=false, Name=Steve Test, SetupOwnerId=00DXXX, 
CreatedDate=2015-07-14 13:13:57, CreatedById=005XXX, 
LastModifiedDate=2016-08-10 22:05:16, LastModifiedById=005XXX, 
SystemModstamp=2016-08-10 22:05:16, Custom_Field__c=test}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the old code uses v20.0.  At some point between v20.0 and v37.0 the behavior of `{List Custom Setting}.getInstance()` changed.  I was able to reproduce the behavior in the [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) selecting version 20.0 and selecting `Apex Execute` from the `Utilities` menu.

Comment: See also this [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000eauWQAQ), which is probably related. I believe there was a change somewhere between version 27.0 and 32.0, but I can't seem to find the notes.

Comment: getInstance(null) is what this refers to, not getInstance().  May be the same result, though.